# Can't access grub to restore sudo

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, grub

I mistakenly ran a command that made sudo no longer a set-uid binary and it's no longer owned by root and now I can use it at all. I want to go into grub to correct this but I can't access grub because my grub timeout is 0 and I can't change the grub config file because it requires root permission (sudo) to write to the file. Any ideas on solutions for any of these problems please?

```
sudo chown -R adstefnum /usr
```

That's the command I ran.

Comment: Boot into a Rescue USB, mount the system filesystem, and then `chown -R root /usr`

Comment: How do I make a rescue USB please?

Comment: Use whatever you used to install Kali. Also, please read [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360) and [Should I use Kali Linux](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) on the official Kali website. Quite simply: if you don't know how to fix this, then you really shouldn't be using Kali. Kali is not a regular operating system, it is a tool for experts. _Anything_ you can do on Kali, you can also do on a regular Linux, so if you just want to learn, use a normal Linux.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm pretty good on kali. I just got some stress and ran the command without double checking. I already tried booting with a bootable disk but it was getting stuck at intrid:/ . I think there are actual rescue disks to use.

Comment: No offense but if you don't know how to make a rescue disk or solve this issue on your own and are making mistakes like this, then you aren't an expert at Linux.

Comment: Burn. Thanks bro

Comment: While I completely agree with what others said about not using kali, it's worth pointing out that if you have a password set for the root account and you know what it is, you can use `su` to get a root shell (su is in /bin, so won't have been affected by your chown).   That's if the system even boots at all - changing the ownership of /usr and everything below it will have broken lots of stuff - fixing that will be nearly impossible, it will be much easier to just blow it away and reinstall from scratch (make a backup of any personal files/scripts/etc first).

Comment: No i don't have a root password set. But thanks. I probably will just back up my system and reinstall.